# Accessing user control on child master page from child master page code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Trying to set the value of a literal user control on my child master page via the code behind of the same master page.

Here is example of the code I am using:

**Global.master**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="GlobalContentPlaceHolderBody" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

**Template.master (child of Global.master)**

```
<asp:Content ID="TemplateContentBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="GlobalContentPlaceHolderBody" Runat="Server">
<asp:Literal ID="MyLiteral1" runat="Server"></asp:Literal>

<p>This is template sample content!</p>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TemplateContentPlaceHolderBody" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**Template.master.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyLiteral1.Text = "Test";
}
```

**ContentPage.aspx**

```
< asp:Content ID="ContentBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="TemplateContentPlaceHolderBody" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Once I am able to achieve this, I will also need to be able to access content on the global and template master pages via content pages.

Comment: I am not seeing any errors, but the literal is not updating.

Comment: This may seem silly, but are you creating a web site, or a web application? If the later, you have compiled your site haven't you?

Comment: Just a web site...not a compile issue.  thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution.  In the template.master (nested child master), I had to put the code in OnLoad event.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    MyLiteral1.Text= "<p>MyLiteral1 Successfully updated from nested template!</p>";
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Very strange...

Basically, I am using the global master as the page that has code shared on every page, then I will have various nested pages to suit each website section.  For the navigation nested template, I want to be able to show if the user is logged in and how many items in shopping cart.

If there is a better way to achieve this, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: This is the way to do it.  It is strange that this didn't work in the Page_Load.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your scenario you want to have your content pages access items from your master pages. If so, you'll need to setup a property to expose them from your master page, and in your content page you can setup a MasterType directive.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092784/how-to-control-elements-on-a-asp-net-master-page-from-child-page/1092857#1092857) for an example.

Comment: Your title sort of conflicts with your last sentence, "... I will also need to be able to access content ... via content pages." The answer I'm proposing covers this situation, unless you're trying to do something from the master pages instead.

Comment: +1 If all we're talking about is accessing a control on a parent master page, the MasterType directive is what we're looking for.

Comment: Ahmad, I was trying to access a control on a nested child master page via it's own code behind.  The fix was to call it in the OnLoad event.

Alexis - MasterType directive is useful for accessing via a content page, not from within a nested master page itself.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is my answer when I thought you were trying to access a control on the child master from the parent master code behind.

You can use a recursive findControl function:

```
protected Control FindControlRecursive(string id, Control parent)
{
    // If parent is the control we're looking for, return it
    if (string.Compare(parent.ID, id, true) == 0)
        return parent;

    // Search through children
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        Control match = FindControlRecursive(id, child);

        if (match != null)
            return match;
    }

    // If we reach here then no control with id was found
    return null;
}
```

Then use this code in your master page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//EDIT: if GlobalContentPlaceHolderBody isn't visible here, use this instead:
//Control c = FindControlRecursive("MyLiteral1", Page.FindControl("GlobalContentPlaceHolderBody"));
    Control c = FindControlRecursive("MyLiteral1", GlobalContentPlaceHolderBody);
    if(c != null)
        ((Literal)c).Text = "Test";
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the protected Control FindControlRecursive?  If I add it to the Template.master.cs, I get the error: The name 'GlobalContentPlaceHolderBody' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: For accessing a user control in the master via a content page, it was simple.  Added the following to the template.master.cs:

    public string ContentLabelDemoPublic
    {
        set
        {
            ContentLabelDemo.Text = value;
        }
    }

and then in the content page I could add:

((MasterPages_Template)Master).ContentLabelDemoPublic = "Label on child master page exposed using public variable updated by content page";

Accessing the nested master page via its own code-behind should not be that difficult.

Comment: GlobalContentPlaceHolderBody was the id of your Container.  If that is not visible to your code, you can use Page.FindControl("GlobalContentPlaceHolderBody");

Comment: You'll want to add the FindControlRecursive to the master page.

Comment: The reason why this is more complex than a child accessing a control on the master is because a master page is always there.  But a child control isn't guaranteed to always be there.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify.. when you say "add the FindControlRecursive to the master page", you mean the parent master or child master?  Also, if it is the child's codebehind, then it should always be there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question.  I thought you were trying to access a control on the child master from the code behind of the global master.  I will update my answer to be more appropriate.

Comment: No worries... I found another solution and posted, but I will try your solution as well and report back. Thanks for the effort so far!

Comment: Still getting error: The name 'GlobalContentPlaceHolderBody' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Chris, I was able to use the recursive find control to access a control in the nested child from the global master as that seems to be the only way.

Comment: Yeah, and that is what the code was intended for.  I'm glad I was able to help, even though it wasn't for the question asked ;)