# ASP.NET: Passing data from content page to master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a label named `headerLabel` in my master page, and I'd like to set its text to the title from the content page. How do I do this?

Comment: you can use [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092784/how-to-control-elements-on-a-asp-net-master-page-from-child-page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your master page create a public property - something along the lines of:

```
public string LabelValue
{
  get{ return this.headerLabel.Text;}
  set{ this.headerLabel.Text = value;}
}
```

Then, on your child page you can do this:

```
((MyMasterPage)this.Master).LabelValue = "SomeValue";
```

Comment: You have to provide a public property `headerlabel` which returns this label. Then this approach is better than the [`FindControl` approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21160299/284240). Otherwise you cannot access it directly since controls are `protected` by default.

Comment: Nice suggestion - I've updated, I always prefer to access properties - I like the idea of having a public property on the master page rather than the public label.

Comment: How do I go about adding a public property? My project says the 'MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 'LabelValue'

Comment: @PhilipLoffler add the first code segment to your master page

Comment: I have done this but I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: @PhilipLoffler where have you added it? In the code behind of the master page class?

Comment: I put it in there and in a script in MasterPage.Master

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45370/discussion-between-liath-and-philip-loffler)

Answer (score 2):

You need to find control by it's id on the content page then set text property of label like this

```
(Label)MasterPage.FindControl("headerLabel").Text="Your Title";
```

it better to check null before assigning the text property like this

```
 Label mylbl= (Label) MasterPage.FindControl("headerLabel");
    if(mylbl!= null)
    {
        mylbl.Text = "Your Title";
    }
```

Comment: Hard coding control names as strings is BAD!

Comment: @Amir I agree to a point but you have to assume some things are set otherwise you could never redirect or write javascript!

Comment: Follow this article. It described all of the way of sending data to master page like itle, Meta Tags, and Other HTML Headers in the master page.



https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/specifying-the-title-meta-tags-and-other-html-headers-in-the-master-page-cs